# line break does not work in Kotlin (with IDEA)

Tags: string, kotlin

I am following a course that uses Kotlin and there is this code

```
fun getName(@PathVariable("name")name: String):String{
        return "Name: $name¥n"
    }
```

In the course it gives a string "Name: Peter(new line)" if the name is Peter, but in my own code the new line is ignored and it prints `¥n`

I wonder why. This has never has happened to me when using other languages or other IDEs.

(note: in Japanese systems ¥n is the new line since we use the yen symbol instead of the opposite/)

Comment: The Kotlin language documentation specifies that `\n` is the newline escape sequence. It makes no mention of this being different on different systems. Have you tried writing `\n` instead, and did it not work? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#characters

Comment: Wow, I have never had any problem when programming in C# or others. I copy pasted \n (since I cannot type it) and it worked.

Comment: If your keyboard mapping doesn't have \, I recommend configuring an alternate keyboard mapping for when you're doing programming. Most operating systems allow you to install multiple keyboard mappings, and define a shortcut for switching between them.